# How to configure dual boot in Windows 7 UEFI setup menu

Tags: linux, windows-7, multi-boot, uefi

How to configure dual boot in Windows 7 boot menu, to boot Linux from external USB SSD drive? Asus X55A laptop, with UEFI firmware interface,  Win 7 Home. Can't figure out how to configure that from UEFI Setup Screen.

[image]

Comment: You have UEFI. Boot correctly enabled but likely Windows 7 and who knows what else probably installed in Legacy/CSM mode. Otherwise you'd see entries like "Windows bootloader manager", etc.

Answer (score -1):

Windows boot loader cannot load Linux. so you need to install grub

Boot from Linux live CD and enter following command

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

Comment: That will not touch default Windows boot process?

Comment: It might. As I commented above your OSes are probably in Legacy mode. This is a well intentioned answer but doesn't consider your actual problem and doesn't warn about the consequences.

Comment: OK, I've got it.  I contacted Asus support, and they say that this model does not support boot from USB drive. "Unfortunately we don't support Linux, don't support dual OS on internal drive and don't support boot any OS from external drive."